# how to set default value of query string in .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to set `overridable default query string` with index.php
like

`example.php/1`

I tried

`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?p=1`

but didn't get success.
can anybody help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your answer:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ \index.php?p=1
```